# Need help interpreting a Energy Meter datasheet

Tags: current-measurement, multimeter, current-transformer, meter, power-meter

I am reading [this](https://www.gavazzionline.com/pdf/EM2172DDS.pdf) datasheet for an energy meter, to start understanding how this market works.

A friend of mine wants to make a test in a small office building to see if it pays having one of these and he asked for my help, and finally I have an excuse to get to know this kind of devices.

I am leaning towards that meter, good price (around 170eur ~ 200USD), but I don't know what CT clamp to buy for it.

I want one clamp for 100A, 200A and around 600A or more.

But looking at the datasheet:

[image]

I am not able to tell which CTs to buy. So far the meters I've studied they have something like `primary coil 100A -> 5A secondary` or `primary coil 100A -> 1A secondary`, `primary coil 100A -> 0.333A secondary`, `primary coil 500A -> 10A secondary`, and so on. But this one is different...

For this meter I am not being able to interpret what's the maximum secondary coil current it can handle, and consequently nor the primary.

Can you help me with some examples covering their ratios (`1.0 to 99.9/ 100 to 999 / 1.00k to 6.00k etc.`?

Thanks!

**PS:** I know the dangers of high voltages and current, and no, I am not going to handle the installation of these devices, nor touch electric boards, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like straightforward but poorly formatted.

Because their display cannot do half digits e.g. 0 to 1.999  they have spec'd it 1 to 99.9 range.

So you would choose this range in programming the meter for use of a 100A CT.

The next range includes both 200A and 600A.

The burden value selected is such that the meter is rated as;
"Current Impedance 5(6)A  = < 0.3VA"

> **So whatever CT ratio you choose the output is 5A or (6A)**

*see page 2 of spec for EM2172D DS ENG 190210*

It looks like it may have been translated to english with somewhat amateur format. But I would never compl;)aint about it.

Comment: It is strange because when I search for Gavazzi CTV3X200A333MV CT (which outputs 333mV -- https://www.dropbox.com/s/5q3catgk2yl1b1n/CTV3X200A333MV.pdf?dl=0), I get this meter related (the EM21 72D). Are you sure it only reads CT complying with 5A secondary? I cannot understand this meter datasheet at all.

Comment: The EM21   the CT turns ratio is 1:600 (that is: 3000A:5A) where the CTV3x200A333mV is  Current ratio 200A/333mV Turns Ratio Np:Ns=1:3000

Comment: The load or "burden" resistor is built into the CTV3x200A333MV so that it is calibrated for excitation current losses so intead of getting 200A/3000= 0.666A into an external load R, you get only 333mV with the internal load R and secondary winding resistance losses and primary core excitation current losses included. so you dont have to add a load R.

Comment: "The EM21 the CT turns ratio is 1:600 (that is: 3000A:5A)" what?

Comment: "CTV3x200A333mV is Current ratio 200A/333mV Turns Ratio Np:Ns=1:3000" So, can this CT be used with EM21? This is so confusing for the wrong reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much world wide, the standard for current transformers is to provide a 5 amp secondary for any selected primary current. Transformers with a 1 amp secondary are not uncommon, but the linked data sheet for the energy meter indicates that use with a 1 amp current transformer does not conform to the listed standard.

The top left corner of page 6 of the linked data sheet shows a graph of accuracy. The best accuracy is for operation between 0.25 and 6 amps or 5% to 120% of the rated primary current. Operation below 1% is shown as a dotted line. I would interpret that as "undefined," "not recommended," or "not guaranteed." If you buy a 600 amp CT, the meter might not be accurate below 6 amps. In addition, the current transformer itself may have a lower limit on recommended accurate current measurement.

Measurement up to 120% of rated current is accurate, but there does not seem to be a description of the consequences of exceeding 120% of the rating. For motor starting inrush currents etc., it would have to be safe to have currents of 500% of rated or more for a few seconds, but measurement accuracy is undefined.

You probably need to read the related standards.

You need to understand what kind power system you are measuring: 3-phase, 4-wire; 3-phase, 3-wire; 2-phase, 3-wire; or 1-phase, 2-wire. Note that 2-phase, 3-wire is either nonexistent or very nearly nonexistent anywhere in the world. Perhaps that is supposed to be 1-phase, 3-wire. That is used for virtually every domestic, retail and office premises in North America.

It would be a good idea to learn enough to have a reasonable understanding of most of the linked data sheet.